# No feasible entries for infix operator "+"

Tags: vhdl

I am designing a 2s complement code but it is showing that error can any one help me with that.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;

entity comp is
port(a : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    y : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end comp;

architecture dataflow of comp is
signal temp: std_logic;
begin
    y<=  not(a) + "00000001";
end dataflow;
```

> Error: D:/modelsim_projects/2scmpliment.vhd(13): No feasible entries
>   for infix operator "+".

Comment: Everyone skips the cause - operators are functions depending on signatures for overload resolution.  You don't have a single function with a signature [std_logic_vector,std_logic_vector return std_logic_vector] visible. You don't have a use clause making the declaration of one visible (from a package declaration). Morten's solution's provide that and makes use of a visible one by using explicit type conversions and available declarations (in package numeric_std).

Answer (score 1):

When using Synopsys packages, you need to add use of the `std_logic_unsigned` package after `std_logic_1164`, like:

```
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

With this you can even use integer notation for addition like:

```
y <= not(a) + 1;
```

Alternative is to use the IEEE VHDL standard `numeric_std` package, with changes like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
  y <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(not(a)) + 1);
```

Comment: There's also package numeric_std_unsigned for those with IEEE Std 1076-2008 compatible simulation and synthesis environments, providing the IEEE compliant equivalent to Synopsys' package std_logic_unsigned.