# full adder 3-bit std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, operation

i am learning vhdl and i get an error when i simulate a 3-bit full adder 
that implements with std_logic_vector (because of ability to use '+' operation)
just an example that our teacher gave us,
forgive me if it is a simple question...
here is code :

```
Library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity adder_3_bit is
    port(
    a,b : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    cin : in std_logic;
    cout : out std_logic;
    sum : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
    );
end adder_3_bit;
architecture behav of adder_3_bit is 
    signal temp : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    begin
    temp <= ('0' & a) + ('0' & b) + ("000" & cin);
    sum <= temp(2 downto 0);
    cout <= temp(3);
    end behav;
```

i get an error when temp is trying to add 0's at then end of 2 bit arrays,
which it says :

```
Line 15: found '0' definitions of operator "+", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "+"ERROR:HDLCompiler:854
```

every body here is the working code:

```
Library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity adder_3_bit is
    port (
    a,b : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    cin : in std_logic;
    cout : out std_logic;
    sum : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
    );
end adder_3_bit;
architecture behav of adder_3_bit is 
    signal temp : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    begin
     temp <= std_logic_vector(('0' & unsigned (a)) + ('0' & unsigned(b)) + ("000" & cin));
    sum <= temp(2 downto 0);
    cout <= temp(3);
end behav;
```

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816958/no-feasible-entries-for-infix-operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816958/no-feasible-entries-for-infix-operator).

Comment: What are you asking? As QuantumRipple indicates in his answer to your unformulated question you can add a use clause - `use ieee.numeric_std.all;` then change your temp assignment expression - `    temp <= std_logic_vector(('0' & unsigned (a)) + ('0' & unsigned(b)) + ("000" & cin));`. Likewise for -2008 you could use numeric_std_unsigned instead of numeric_std and not change your temp assignment expression. Operators can be overloaded. The declarations for the functions implementing them have to be visible to overload they'd be made visible with use clauses.

Comment: @user1155120thanks! this now works. forgive me because i already said i am learning vhdl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any additional libraries, you cannot add signals of type `std_logic_vector`. There is no `+` operator defined that takes two `std_logic_vector` arguments. The correct way to do this is to include the numeric_std package and cast your arguments to unsigned for your additions.

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & a) + unsigned('0' & b) + unsigned("000" & cin));
```

In practice, most people don't create a whole entity for such a simple operation so there are fewer casts as your signals are in the correct type for the data already (numbers use unsigned, collections of bits use std_logic_vector), which is why this looks a bit awkward.

You could also get by doing this with the synopsis package (std_logic_unsigned) and it would look a little cleaner (no casts), but that package is not part of the VHDL standard and its use has been deprecated.

Comment: thanks for answering,
but it gave me another error  :
Line 17: found '4' definitions of operator "&", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "&"

Comment: So before the problem was that there was no defined function using the `+` operator that took two `std_logic_vector`s. 

Now your problem is that there is more than one function using the `&` operator.
In this case, it is because the result of your concatenation (before casting to `unsigned`) might be `std_logic_vector`, `std_ulogic_vector`, `signed`, or `unsigned` (all 4 `&` functions exist) since we want an unsigned, we actually don't need a cast and can just explicitly declare the type by doing `unsigned'()` instead of `unsigned()`. Note that we still need the `std_logic_vector` cast.

Comment: would you give a complete example?

Comment: If my comment wasn't clear enough, due to the abundance of concatenation functions (`&`) and the arguments you are using, you actually need to use a qualified expression (http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/qualifex.html) instead of a cast to unsigned. You'll need to figure out where to add the 3 characters to make this change yourself.