# Numeric operation in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

i'm new in vhdl programming language. i'm trying to make a full adder with "+" operator , i made the code and l compiled as well but when i simulate it the output are very weird and doesn't mutch with the full adder outputs,i think that the error probably gonna be in the vector length, but i can't fix it.

```
    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity adder is
port (a,b,c : in std_logic;
    s,d : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture arc_adder of adder is
signal z : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
signal w : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0); 
begin 
z <= ('0'&a + ('0'&b));
w <= '0'&z + "00"&c;
s<=w(0);
d<=w(1);

end architecture;
```

Comment: What do you need `std_logic_unsigned` for?

Comment: @Staszek because he's incorrectly using `std_logic_vector` instead of `unsigned` types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [full adder 3-bit std\_logic\_vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247478/full-adder-3-bit-std-logic-vector)

Comment: The expression being assigned to w has two operators with the same precedence, they'll be associated in left to right order which can be shown with parentheses: `(('0' & z) + "00") & c;`. That'll end up with a value length 4 that's equivalent to '0' & z & c. That's not what you want.  z can have a binary value of "00", "01" or "10". With a carry in (c) w can have those values and "11" so only needs the same range 1 downto 0.   `w <= z + ('0' & c);` or eliminating z `w <= '0' & a + ('0' & b) + ('0' & c);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use unsigned to type with the "+" operator.

Unsigned type is included in ieee.numeric_std.all

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is
port (a,b,c : in std_logic;
    s,d : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture arc_adder of adder is
signal z : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
signal w : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0); 
begin 
z <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0'&a) + unsigned('0'&b));
w <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0'&z) + unsigned("00"&c));
s<=w(0);
d<=w(1);

end architecture;
```

Comment: This would look neater if `z` and `w` had type `unsigned` as well.